# Privileges of an Application

Tags: c#, security, privilege

Is there a way to get the privileges associated with a C# program?  If yes, how?

I know that in C, you have to create a token and make use of the GetTokenInformation() method to get information about the token.

Is there something similar in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My C# is a little rusty, but if i remember correctly this does the trick

```
WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
```

Comment: Thanks :)  How do I print the information on the screen though?

Comment: What information do you want? That wasnt part of your question

Comment: No problem, remember to mark the answers that helped as answered :)